# How to use tsvector_update_trigger with array types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I'm using the pg_search gem to add full text search to a table in my app.

My problem is when trying to create a trigger to keep the tsv column up to date after any change, this is my migration:

```
class AddStoreItemsIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_column :store_items, :tsv, :tsvector
    add_index :store_items, :tsv, using: "gin"

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON store_items FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
      tsvector_update_trigger(
        tsv, 'pg_catalog.english', title, full_description, recommended_age, related_intelligences
      );
    SQL
  end

  ...
end
```

In this case, the `related_intelligences` column is an Array, so when trying to query this I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "related_intelligences" is not of a character type
```

How can I include arrays within this tsv vector column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
class AddStoreItemsIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_column :store_items, :tsv, :tsvector
    add_index :store_items, :tsv, using: 'gin'

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE FUNCTION update_tsv() RETURNS trigger AS $$
      BEGIN
        new.tsv :=
          to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')) ||
          to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.full_description,'')) ||
          to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.recommended_age,'')) ||
          to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(array_to_string(new.related_intelligences, ' '),''));
        return new;
      END
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

      CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON store_items FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tsv();
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TRIGGER tsvectorupdate
      ON store_items;
      DROP FUNCTION update_tsv();
    SQL

    remove_index :store_items, :tsv
    remove_column :store_items, :tsv
  end
end
```

The `tsvector_update_trigger` can't be used for array columns, instead I created a custom function based on the code sample from the [postgresql search features page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS).

I used `array_to_string` to convert the array elements to text.