# Passing an array to a tsvector trigger function in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm creating a tsvector column, and following the excellent Postgres documentation here to create a trigger function:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS

I've run into an issue though, and that is one of my columns is an array of strings. When I try to set this trigger function, I get an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON photos FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 
                        'pg_catalog.english', 
                        title, 
                        description, 
                        array_to_string(tags, ' ')); -- this is the problematic line
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 8:   array_to_string(tags, ' ') );
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 197
```

Is there a better way to pass the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the built-in function only accepts text or compatible text datatypes.

I realize it's a lot more work than using the built-in, but you can always write your own trigger function, since it can access the entire record (as `NEW`).  I'm making some assumptions about your table.

```
create or replace function photos_insert_update_trigger()
returns trigger
language plpgsql as
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    NEW.tsv := to_tsvector ('english',
      NEW.title || ' ' ||
      NEW.description || ' ' ||
      array_to_string (NEW.tags, ' '));
    return NEW;
  END;
$BODY$;

create trigger insert_update_photos_trigger
before insert or update on photos
for each row
execute procedure photos_insert_update_trigger();

insert into photos (title, description, tags)
values ('Spaceballs', 'Mel Brooks Star Wars', array['Dark Helmet', 'Yogurt']);
```

I don't work with tsvectors a lot, so it's possible my interpretation of how the text turns into the tsvector might be a bit off, but the bottom line is with your own trigger function you will have complete flexibility on how you want to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you, after more digging, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090712/how-to-use-tsvector-update-trigger-with-array-types-in-postgresql I tried a custom function similar to what you suggested but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to work without wrapping the array_to_string bit in its own to_tsvector function.

Comment: Just confirming, I gave this format another try and it worked. I must have had some syntax error before. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it worked...  wow, that link you posted was something.  I would not have come up with that.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works, but just FYI I've tweaked to include the coalesce function, so this is what I ended up using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION photos_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv :=
    to_tsvector('english', 
      coalesce(new.title, '') || ' ' ||
      coalesce(new.description, '') || ' ' ||
      coalesce(array_to_string(new.tags, ' '), ''));
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON photos FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE photos_trigger();
```

Comment: I recall reading this a while back...  it seems the `concat` function handles nulls differently than the `||` operator, so that may be an alternative to multiple coalesce statements.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52820875/1278553.  Nothing wrong with what you have done; just food for thought.